# Next value by group in SAS

Tags: group-by, sas

I am trying to create a new variable that takes the next value in a group. In particular, I have:

```
User   Quarter
 A     2012Q1
 A     2012Q2
 A     2012Q3
```

My desired output would be:

```
User   Quarter  Next_Quarter
 A     2012Q1    2012Q2
 A     2012Q2    2012Q3
 A     2012Q3     n/a
```

I have tried to have a counter for each customer, but I am not sure where I should go from there...

Answer (score 0):

There is no an easy way to look forward in a data step.  What you can do is reverse the order, use the lag function to get the value, and reorder appropriately.

```
data have;
input User $  Quarter $;
datalines;
A     2012Q1
A     2012Q2
A     2012Q3
B     2012Q1
B     2012Q2
B     2012Q3
;

/*Reverse the order*/
proc sort data=have;
by user descending quarter;
run;

/*Use Lag() to get the previous value (next since we reversed it)*/
data want;
set have;
by user;

tmp = lag(quarter);

if ^first.user then
    Next_Quarter = tmp;
else
    Next_Quarter = "n/a";

drop tmp;
run;

/*Re-sort to the proper order*/
proc sort data=want;
by user quarter;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra SET statement with `FIRSTOBS=2` to "look ahead".  Make sure to account for any BY groups.

```
data want ;
  set have end=eof ;
  by user;
  if not eof then set have(keep=Quarter rename=(Quarter=Next_Quarter) firstobs=2) ;
  if last.user then call missing(Next_Quarter);
run;
```

If you do not have BY groups then change the last IF to

```
  if eof then call missing(Next_Quarter);
```

Comment: This works really well! Thank you!